# sharedPreference arraylist getting indexoutofboundsexception in for loop in thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, arraylist, sharedpreferences

For some reasons when I put the arraylists that were saved in the sharedPreferences file, they work fine when I got a specific index of the arraylist, but in a for loop, I keep getting an index out of bounds exception and I don't know why.  I tried many things, but none of them work. Is there a specific reason that I am getting this error and what are some ways I can fix it?

```
  if ((sharedPreferences.contains("grandmaCounter")) && (sharedPreferences.contains("listX")) && (sharedPreferences.contains("listY"))) {

grandmaCounter = sharedPreferences.getInt("grandmaCounter", -1);
final Thread grandmaReloader = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < grandmaCounter; i++) {



            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type type = new TypeToken < List < Double >> () {}.getType();
            final List < Double > X = gson.fromJson(sharedPreferences.getString("listX", ""), type);
            final List < Double > Y = gson.fromJson(sharedPreferences.getString("listY", ""), type);

            final int finalI = i;
            final int finalI1 = i;
            final int finalI2 = i;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final ImageView grandma = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);


                    grandma.setId(View.generateViewId());
                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    grandma.setLayoutParams(params);
                    layout.addView(grandma);
                    double x;
                    double y;
                    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
                    constraintSet.clone(layout);
                    constraintSet.connect(grandma.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, layout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP);
                    constraintSet.connect(grandma.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, layout.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
                    constraintSet.connect(grandma.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, layout.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT);
                    constraintSet.connect(grandma.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, layout.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
                    constraintSet.applyTo(layout);
                    grandma.getLayoutParams().height = 250;
                    if (X.get(finalI2) != null) {
                        x = X.get(finalI2);
                        grandma.setX((float) x);
                    }
                    if (Y.get(finalI2) != null) {
                        y = Y.get(finalI2);
                        grandma.setY((float) y);

                    }
                    grandma.requestLayout();
                    //        Log.d("tagest", String.valueOf(X.get(0)));



                    grandma.setImageResource(R.drawable.grandmafigure);

                }
            });

        }

    }
});
grandmaReloader.start();
```